# ExceptionHandler with the use of CustomErrorDecoder for Feign client

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am using openFeign from Netflix to create REST communication with external API. I have used Feign errorDecoder to handle feign exceptions.

```
public class MyErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {

private final ErrorDecoder defaultErrorDecoder = new Default();

@Override
public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
    if (response.status() == 404) {
        return new MyNotFoundException();

    return defaultErrorDecoder.decode(methodKey, response);
}}
```

To pick up MyErrorDecoder by Spring I have put it in the ApplicationContext:

```
@Bean
public MyErrorDecoder myErrorDecoder() {
  return new MyErrorDecoder();
}
```

I have also implemented ExceptionTranslator class for handling those exceptions.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionTranslator {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionTranslator.class);


    @ExceptionHandler(MyNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ErrorData myNotFoundExc(MyNotFoundException exception){
        log.warn(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        return new ErrorData(exception.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ErrorData processRuntimeException(Exception exception){
        log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        return new ErrorData(exception.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Whenever application is throwing `MyNotFoundException` it is consumed by `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` instead of `@ExceptionHandler(MyNotFoundException.class)`. 
When I removed `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` it works as I want.

Does anyone how an idea how to achieve behaviour that I am expecting?

Comment: i would suggest create another custom exception class instead of using java.lang.Exception
That will solve this problem.